# From paid app to free inapp purchase on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, android-inapp-purchase

I want to make my paid app a free app with inapp purchase, but I want that all people that have just bought the app don't have to pay again the inapp,  is there a way to do that? Is there some official documentation to read? I have searched a lot but without luck.

Best regards

Comment: To change the app mode you are creating obviously a new free app with IAP. There is no way to access a user's purchases to determine if he/she bought your other.

Answer (score 0):

One possible tricky method should be notifying current users to sent you their google email account. By putting google email account into test account, there will be able to purchase in-app purchase for free.